# Python Whois Module Error

Tags: python, whois

I am trying to run the following code on Windows Powershell, but it gives an error "Module is not callable."

```
import whois
w = whois.whois('yahoo.com')

print w
```

What am I doing wrong? I even pip installed the whois module. Still no difference.

Please help.

Comment: On windows it also crashes for me: 'WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified'. It works correctly on my Debian Linux machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the [whois documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pywhois/) is out of date; change the line to

```
w = whois.query('yahoo.com')
```

You can do `help(whois)` in an interactive terminal (after `import whois`) to see more up-to-date documentation.

Comment: Query is not working. Gives the same not callable error. I am guessing the module has been scraped off. However, thank you, your answer was right if the module existed.